# Solving following first order partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $h=h(w,z)$ I want to solve following differential equation

\begin{align}
z \frac{\partial h}{\partial z} + 2 w\frac{-a^2 + w + z^2 + \sqrt{4a^2 z^2 + (-a^2 + w + z^2)^2}}{a^2 + w + z^2 + \sqrt{4 a^2 z^2 + (-a^2 + w + z^2)^2}} \frac{\partial h}{\partial w} =0
\end{align}

Actually I know [even though I don't know how to solve]
\begin{align}
 h[w,z] = \frac{\sqrt{2} z}{\sqrt{-a^2 + w + z^2 + \sqrt{4a^2 z^2 + (-a^2 + w + z^2)^2}}}
\end{align}
this is a solution by plugging the above equation.

Is this is a unique solution[upto scaling or up to translation]? Is there any way to derive a general solution to this equation?

Comment: Do you confirm $-a^2 + w^\color{red}2 + z^2 + \cdots$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Thanks for pointing out, it should be $-a^2 + w + z^2 + \cdots$

Comment: This can be solved by the method of characteristics. Without initial data it can not be unique.